Why does RS232 receive the wrong HEX value?
I don't understand why RS232 is receiving the wrong HEX value.
For example:

Like send from PC 0x01 but on the STM32, its receive 7F.
If send from   PC 0x03 and on the STM32, its receive 7E.

I tried to check the RS232 with 2 PC and it's totally ok, but when I try to send it to STM32, the reading doesn't seem to be correct. I checked on google that it's something due to the ASCII. But I don't know how to resolve it.
I am using the standard function
HAL_UART_Receive(&huart3, receiveData, 2, 100);

Is there a method that is easier to understand?

Notice how most of your bits in the example numbers are 0 (both for 0x01 and 0x03), but 7F and 7E have almost all bits set, except for the most significant one. Is it possible you have wrong signal polarity/idle level? Check the line level when UART is idle, and make sure PC and MCU agree on it.

This is a hardware problem.  Consider that you accidentally swapped the receive and ground wires.

Thank llya for the hint, Checked the code again, notice the UART configuration was set wrong. After changing the invert to disable. TX and RX work correctly. Below are the 2 configuration.
huart3.AdvancedInit.TxPinLevelInvert = UART_ADVFEATURE_TXINV_DISABLE;
huart3.AdvancedInit.RxPinLevelInvert = UART_ADVFEATURE_RXINV_DISABLE;

